# VSCode integrated terminal in Remote SSH ignores /etc/profile.d/*

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code

When I use VSCode integrated terminal to login a Linux remote workstation with Remote SSH, the shell scripts in `/etc/profile.d/*` will not be executed. Some other scripts like `~/.bash_profile` may also be ignored.

For example, if I have a `/etc/profile.d/cuda.sh` file that exports some `PATH`, the `PATH` environment variable will be modified accordingly in normal SSH, but not in VSCode terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Since the VSCode terminal act differently than SSH login, you should add the following in your remote SSH configuration (`File > Preferences > Settings > Remote`):

```json
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": [
    "--login", "-i"
],
```

If you workstation is Windows, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50332206/).

Answer (score 2):

These are the settings I had to set in `Settings > Features > Terminal > Integrated > Profiles:Linux` (click to edit in settings.json (for me the settings file was: `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`)):

```
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
          "path": "bash",
          "args": ["--login", "-i"],
          "icon": "terminal-bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
          "path": "zsh"
        },
        "fish": {
          "path": "fish"
        },
        "tmux": {
          "path": "tmux",
          "icon": "terminal-tmux"
        },
        "pwsh": {
          "path": "pwsh",
          "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        }
      }
```